# Import Android APK Archive Into Another Project And Accessed As JAR

Tags: android, apk

Can an Android APK archive be imported into another Android project and accessed the same way as a JAR archive can?

Answer (score 1):

No, .apk are for apps.

You are probably thinking of .aar

See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html